# Specify dst_rule for ambiguous dates in pendulum.parse

Tags: python, dst, pendulum

I have to parse time-series data from CSV files in an application.
The timestamps sometimes are in locale time with DST transitions.
I want to use python-pendulum for the parsing of the date strings.
Is it possible to specify the `dst_rule` when calling the `pendulum.parse` method? It seems to be ignored:

```
>>> str(pendulum.parse('2017-10-29 02:30:00', tz='Europe/Berlin', dst_rule=pendulum.PRE_TRANSITION))
'2017-10-29T02:30:00+01:00'
>>> str(pendulum.parse('2017-10-29 02:30:00', tz='Europe/Berlin', dst_rule=pendulum.POST_TRANSITION))
'2017-10-29T02:30:00+01:00'
```

I need the first string to be '2017-10-29T02:30:00+**02**:00' in my application.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by instantiating the DateTime instance again after parsing:

```
dt = pendulum.parse('2017-10-29 02:30:00', tz='Europe/Berlin')
dt = pendulum.datetime(
    dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second, dt.microsecond,
    tz='Europe/Berlin', dst_rule=pendulum.PRE_TRANSITION
)
```

Output now is `'2017-10-29T02:30:00+02:00'`